# JavaScript XSLTProcessor transformToDocument result is 'Document is empty'

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have valid XMLDocument objects, one is XML and the other is XSL 1.0.

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:variable name="empty_string"/>
<xsl:variable name="earthing_cable" select="'AAA'"/>
<xsl:key name="elements" match="INST[./CSTICS/CSTIC[@CHARC='ALT_PRODUCT_NUMBER']]|INST[name(..)='PART'][./CSTICS/CSTIC[@CHARC='VBOM']]"
         use="@COMPLETE"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
{
 "solution": [
 {
   "name" :  "<xsl:value-of select="SOLUTION/CONFIGURATION/@NAME"/>",
   "product" :  "<xsl:value-of select="SOLUTION/CONFIGURATION/INST/@OBJ_KEY"/>",
   "kbname" :  "<xsl:value-of select="SOLUTION/CONFIGURATION/@KBNAME"/>",
   "objects":
   {

  }
  }
  ]
}
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="get_container">
<xsl:param name="port"/>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><SOLUTION></SOLUTION>
```

This is my code (xml and xsl are valid XMLDocument objects):

```
xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xml);
console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDocument));
```

And console.log is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body><parsererror style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black"><h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3><div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 2 at column 1: Document is empty
</div><h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3></parsererror></body></html>
```

Here I've tested XML and XSL and it works fine:

https://xslttest.appspot.com/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
{
 "solution": [
 {
   "name" :  "",
   "product" :  "",
   "kbname" :  "",
   "objects":
   {

  }
  }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is to transform to fragment, and this works fine.

```
resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
```

Comment: Well, have you ever written and loaded an "XML" document without a root element into a DOM tree? It is kind of odd that you expect that to happen with a method `transformToDocument` supposed to return a DOM document, that result you create with XSLT is a kind of result XSLT can produce but it is certainly not an XML document, lacking any root element. As the JavaScript API for XSLTProcessor is tree/node based and does not offer a direct way to simply give a serialized result using `transformToFragment` is not really a workaround but rather the logical approach to the type of result you want.

Comment: XSLT should produce XML, <xsl:output method="xml"/>, no?

Comment: I don't know what you consider XML but the result you show is certainly not an XML document (https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-well-formed). And the XSLT output method `xml` does neither require or ensure you get an XML document, rather https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-XML-Output-Method says "The xml output method outputs the result tree as a well-formed XML external general parsed entity" which has its place in the XML spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-extParsedEnt but is not an XML document. The relevant tree structure in the DOM world is a document fragment.